# Ignore enter keypress on dropdown with DropdownStyle=DropDownList

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've got a combobox, which the user can type into to filter out results.

To implement this, I've set the dropDownStyle to DropdownList and set the KeyUp event as follows

```
Private Sub cbRPP_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles cbRPP.KeyUp
    If boredUserProtection Then Return

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        e.Handled = True
        Return 'Boss doesn't want enter to do anything
    End If
    ComboKeyPressed()
End Sub


Private Sub cbRPP_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbRPP.SelectionChangeCommitted
    If boredUserProtection Then Return 'boredUserProtection = a flag to prevent the user from typing into the box once they've entered some text
    Try
        boredUserProtection = True
        menuButton.Select()
        TooltipNotify("Loading")
        cbRPP.Text = String.Empty
        LoadRegion()
        menuButton.Select()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorReporter.Program.ReportError(ex, "RPPCalibator", "Handled Gracefully")
    Finally
        boredUserProtection = False
    End Try
End Sub
```

The problem is that my boss has now asked me to prevent any action from occuring when he presses the enter key.

I've attempted to achieve this by intercepting the keypress and suppressing if enter, but it seems that this doesn't work when dropdownStyle=dropdownList

```
Private Sub cbRPP_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles cbRPP.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = vbCrLf Then
        e.Handled = True
        Return 'Boss doesn't want enter to do anything
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cbRPP_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles cbRPP.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        e.Handled = True
        Return 'Boss doesn't want enter to do anything
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm just wondering if anyone can shed any light on how I can prevent any events happening on enter keyprss, as the one piece of advice I can readily find on Google (intercepting KeyDown or KeyUp) don't seem to work.

(I'm a pragmatist, so whatever form of solution you have would be much appreciated)

Comment: Keep the `KeyDown` event with just `If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then e.SuppressKeyPress = True`. Setting `SuppressKeyPress` to True also sets `e.Handled` to the same value. See the [.Net source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/KeyEvent.cs,182). Remove other Keyboard event handlers. Unless you have other Keys filters you're not showing here.

Comment: For posterity: This does not make any difference